# How to display text from one activity to another activity layout?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a google maps project whereby a user can long press on a specific point on the map to place a marker.  Then when tapping on that marker in brings up a custom dialog window.  All of this works great, but what I need to do is show the Lat and Lng of that marker in the text view of the custom dialog window.

So for the custom dialog I have the following:

```
 public class CustDialog {

public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialogbox);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
    text.setText(msg);

    Button dialogBtn_cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
    dialogBtn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    Button dialogBtn_okay = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_okay);
    dialogBtn_okay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
```

The on the marker click event I have this line of code to display the Custom Dialog window:

```
ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
alert.showDialog(MapsActivity.this, "New Marker Point");
```

To get the current position of the marker I added these lines to the marker click event:

```
LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
```

And when I try to add the text view to display the text:

```
TextView txtView = findViewById(R.id.txt_location);
txtView.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);
```

So the full on marker click event will be:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
            LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
            ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
            alert.showDialog(MapsActivity.this, "New Marker Point");
            TextView txtView = findViewById(R.id.txt_position);
            txtView.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);

            return false;
        }
    }));
```

I then get the following error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

Is there a way to pass the text from the MapsActivity class to the CustDialog class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first have the latitude and longitude that you call the dialog to pass the dialog and after the dialogue you can easily use the latitude and longitude effectively and in this case you do not have a problem or you can you have. Use it wherever you want.

**1 - your custom dialog**

```
public class ViewDialog extends Dialog {
Context _context;

TextView txtView ;

public ViewDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.DialogStyle);
    this._context=context;

}


public void  showDialog(String marketName, LatLng latLng) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // optional  code
    setContentView(R.layout.modal_view_dialog);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN); // optional  code


        txtView=findViewById(R.id.txt_position);  // your textView witch in  your dialog
      txtView.setText(latLng!=null ?  " Latitude:"+latLng.latitude+"  Longitude:"+latLng.longitude   : "latLng is failed !");
 }


 /// another method of dialog with you want to use


 }
```

**2-call dialog in your method**

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener((new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
        ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog(MapsActivity.this);
        alert.showDialog("New Marker Point",latLng);
        alert.show();


        return false;
    }
}));
```